# Retrieve Records from paypal csv file

Tags: php, csv

I want a user should be able to upload a paypal csv file and retrieve all the records from that uploaded file where type='Payment Processed' and store it in a database table.It should be available in the following format:

'Heading':'Value'

The format of the csv is:

```
"Transaction ID","Reference Transaction ID","Date","Type","Subject","Item Number","Item Name","Invoice ID","Name","Email","Shipping Name","Shipping Address Line 1","Shipping Address Line 2","Shipping Address City","Shipping State/Province","Shipping Zip/Postal Code","Shipping Address Country","Shipping Method","Address Status","Contact Phone Number","Gross Amount","Receipt ID","Custom Field","Option 1 Name","Option 1 Value","Option 2 Name","Option 2 Value","Note","Auction Site","Auction User ID","Item URL","Auction Closing Date","Insurance Amount","Currency","Fees","Net Amount","Shipping & Handling Amount","Sales Tax Amount","To Email","Time","Time Zone"

"1T","",5/5/2010 2:10:44 PM,"Payment Processed","CFP Self Study Kit","1","CFP Self Study Kit","","User1","user1@gmail.com","","","","","","","","","N","","68.18","R1","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-2.62","65.56","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","01:40","Asia/Calcutta"
"2T","",5/19/2010 4:04:08 PM,"Payment Processed","CFP Self Study Kit","1","CFP Self Study Kit","","User2","user2@gmail.com","","","","","","","","","N","","68.18","R2","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-2.62","65.56","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","03:34","Asia/Calcutta"
"3T","1RT",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","17492.6","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta"
"4T","2RT",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-393.36","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","0","-393.36","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta"
"5T","",5/19/2010 5:28:45 PM,"Transfer to Bank Initiated","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-17492.6","0","0","","04:58","Asia/Calcutta"
"6T","",5/20/2010 5:38:02 PM,"Transfer to Bank Completed","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-17492.6","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-17492.6","0","0","","05:08","Asia/Calcutta"
"7T","",5/21/2010 12:32:37 PM,"Payment Processed","FP - LVC Plus","","FP - LVC Plus","","User3","user3@gmail.com","User3","NEW DELHI","BEHIND KARNATAKA BANK LD","SOUTH","NEW DELHI","110023","IN","","N","","283.96","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","-9.95","274.01","0","0","receiver@gmail.com","00:02","Asia/Calcutta"
"8T","",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Transfer to Bank Initiated","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-12569.85","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta"
"9T","3RT",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-274.01","","","","","","","","","","",,"","USD","0","-274.01","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta"
"10T","4RT",5/25/2010 4:40:48 PM,"Currency Conversion Completed","","","",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","12569.85","0","0","","04:10","Asia/Calcutta"
"11T","",5/26/2010 4:57:39 PM,"Transfer to Bank Completed","P1006","","P1006",""," ","","","","","","","","","","N","","-12569.85","","","","","","","","","","",,"","INR","0","-12569.85","0","0","","04:27","Asia/Calcutta"
"Total","-247.05 USD","-15.19","-262.24"
"Total","0.00 INR","0.00","0.00"
```

Please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [str_getcsv](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) (PHP >= 5.3) are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
$fp = fopen('paypal.csv');
$ln = 0;

while (!feof($fp)) {
    $line = fgetcsv($fp);
    if ($ln === 0) {
        // This will be the column headers
    } else {
        // Perform array manipulation here
    }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: i am getting this result while doing echo $line[0]; inside if($ln==0) condition

"Search Transactions Results"�∀吀爀愀渀猀愀挀琀椀漀渀 䤀䐀∀"1T"�∀㈀吀∀"3T"�∀㐀吀∀"5T"�∀㘀吀∀"7T"�∀㠀吀∀"9T"�∀㄀　吀 ∀"11T"�∀吀漀琀愀氀∀"Total"

Comment: @Pankaj: Doesn't sound to me like you are processing the csv you mentioned originally as "Search Transactions Results" is not one of the headers (though it should work regardless).  What is the first line of the csv you are trying to process now?